# Azure functions error communicating with a databricks notebook

Tags: azure-functions, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a connection between azure functions and databricks notebook to pull data from the notebook.
That was working fine until 7th of Feb, but then I started getting an error without a sensible error code. I have
attached the stack trace and the error message. Have also provided a screenshot of the actual error in code. Any help is appreciated.

```
 WorkflowException: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED Caused by: NotebookExecutionException: FAILED

    at com.databricks.workflow.WorkflowDriver.run(WorkflowDriver.scala:71)
    at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.NotebookUtilsImpl.run(NotebookUtilsImpl.scala:122)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:1)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:43)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:45)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:47)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:49)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw.<init>(command--1:51)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read.<init>(command--1:53)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$.<init>(command--1:57)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$.<clinit>(command--1)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:902)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:855)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:518)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED
    at com.databricks.workflow.WorkflowDriver.run0(WorkflowDriver.scala:117)
    at com.databricks.workflow.WorkflowDriver.run(WorkflowDriver.scala:66)
    at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.NotebookUtilsImpl.run(NotebookUtilsImpl.scala:122)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:1)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:43)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:45)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:47)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command--1:49)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$$iw.<init>(command--1:51)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read.<init>(command--1:53)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$.<init>(command--1:57)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$read$.<clinit>(command--1)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at $line1f0f2874076241fca3dba850716c513d25.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:219)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:902)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:855)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:518)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notebook in a databricks cluster keeps a cache while the cluster is running. If you add an import statement and then remove it, the notebook still has a cached instance of that import and will continue to work. Running code in Visual Studio against the notebook creates a new context and therefore the said import is no longer available and blows up with not a useful error. Started building up the notebook on a new one line by line and as soon as I added my culprit line I knew what the issue was.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: It would be nice if the code is posted with a code fence, not pictures.